# ImagePickerController function memory leak problems

Tags: swift, xcode, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller, uiimagepickercontrollermediatype

I am new to programming in general and was having trouble with memory leak problems with the following code specifically involving the "imagePickerController." The leaks only occur after the UIimagePickerController is dismissed after selecting an image. Thank you for any help fixing this.

```
let imagePicked = UIImagePickerController()

 @IBAction func addPhoto(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.allowsEditing = false

    imagePicked.delegate = self

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Image", message: "Choose From", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        pickerController.sourceType = .camera
        self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let photosLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photos Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil)


    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(photosLibraryAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}



@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        var newImageView = UIImageView()
        newImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        newImageView.center = textView.center

        textView.addSubview(newImageView)

    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

EDIT ONE:

Thank you I have removed `@objc` in front of `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` as well as the extra `UIImagePickerController` object, but I am still having the same problem. I have also tried `picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` but that is still not fixing the problem.

And yes I am pretty sure it is a memory leak error as I've ran the tester and after putting pictures into the app from the photos library or the camera I am getting this:
[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x1gg.png)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXCJi.png)

Also after adding several pictures the app will crash with "Terminated due to memory problem"

Comment: you don't need the `@objc` in front of the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method, also, why do you have two separate `UIImagePickerController` objects?

Comment: Are you actually having a memory leak or some other problem (more likely)?

Comment: Have tried with `picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: @Alper  Yes I am pretty sure it is a memory leak error as I've ran the tester and after putting pictures into the app from the photos library or the camera I am getting a memory error (check edit in post for pictures)

Also after adding several pictures the app will crash with "Terminated due to memory problem"

Comment: @Mannopson Yes I've just tried that but it is not fixing my issue

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Thank you I've just fixed that but still getting the same problem.

Comment: You're leaking a CFString? I mean: this is a manual action. You would have to take a picture like that a bunch of times to even notice a significant memory increase.